# Impossible to add a relationship between contacts / organisations

Tags: wordpress, relationships

When I add a Relationship to a Contact or an Organisation, the list of Relationship Types is displayed in background and I cannot select one of them. See screenshot:
[image]
Any idea ?
I use CiviCRM 15.7.0 under WP (last version)

Comment: This seems to be working in the wp demo site: https://wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org/

Unless I'm missing a step when trying to recreate the error.

Comment: The screenshot looks like they're disconnected so maybe a js/css issue. Are there any errors in the browser dev console?

Comment: Thanks Craig yes I've also seen that...

Comment: @Demerit : I've not seen any errors so far... but if it's working on the demo site event if this one is in the last alpha version, I suspect something else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This case has been solved. We found that there is an incompatibility with the popular Divi Theme we are using between WP and CiviCRM. We can provide details if needed.